# Making that little butter thing you put on top of steak

Tags: butter, steak, plating

So, how do I do it?  It's delicious and adds a bit of class.  Any suggestions as to what I should compose it out of?

Comment: You mean just a curl of butter? There are gadgets out there that will shape the butter for you... they're called butter curlers. If that's not what you mean, you may need to be a bit more specific.

Comment: Are you asking for a recipe for flavoured butter? Or are you asking for a technique to shape it? Or both? I'd suggest roasted garlic + butter + parsley, rolled up into a log/cylinder, refrigerated and then a slice cut before service.

Comment: Yeah, are you talking about a curl or quenelle? A compound butter? Help?

Comment: I had no idea that "quenelle" had a name... a fancy restaurant we go to shapes their in-house ice cream like that. Learn something new ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're referring to a [*compound butter*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_butter).  They usually contain butter and herbs such as sage, parsley, rosemary, thyme, etc., salt, and occasionally lemon, pepper and/or garlic.

For steak it might also include a strongly flavored soft cheese such as a blue cheese such as Gorgonzola or Stilton (my favorite, but my wife hates it).

For example:

[Alton Brown's Compound Butter](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/compound-butter-recipe.html)

[Bobby Flay's Blue Cheese Butter](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/bobby-flay/grilled-filet-with-blue-cheese-butter-recipe.html)

[Culinary Arts Herb Butter for Steak](http://culinaryarts.about.com/od/buttersauces/r/hotelbutter.htm)